# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Пишу скрипт на php, который по запросу пользователя выводит список документов, по 10 на страницу, все ок, все работает. Но если в запросе указать то, чего нет, выдает вот такую ошибку.

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

сам код такого типа

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `nal` WHERE `name`LIKE \"%$search%\" AND `remainder` > 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $start_from, $on_page";
$res = mysql_query($query);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
```

Как я понял $res возвращает значение False, и поэтому дальше и вылазит ошибка, как правильнее исправить. Добавить if перед while? Я пробовал перед этим просто написать что если равно false вывести echo результатов нет и exit, но он вывел мне и сообщение, и ошибку.

Comment: что отдает $res если написать такой код $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

Comment: скорее всего у Вас ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);

if (!$res) {
    echo "Не удается успешно выполнить запрос ($query). Ответ базы данных: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    echo "Записи не найдены, просто выходим";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
```

В таком случае вы увидите причину по которой не работает ваш код.

Comment: выдал Не удается успешно выполнить запрос (SELECT * FROM `nal` WHERE `name`LIKE "%ghjfgh%" AND `remainder` > 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT -10, 10). Ответ базы данных: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10, 10' at line 1
Если я просто буду выводить echo при этой ошибке, что результатов нет, это не сильно скажется на запросе?

Comment: Ну тут ошибка синтаксиса у вас, первый параметр лимита указан как -10, а такого не может быть, переменной $start_from делайте значение 0 и больше и тогда запрос отработает

Comment: можете подсказать еще в чем. Сейчас начало у меня считается так $start_from = ($current_page - 1) * $on_page; то есть получает данные от числа (текущая страница - 1) * количество записей на странице, а раз результата нет, то и получается - 10, как правильней прекратить продолжение? Просто if добавить, что если -10, то не выполнять дальше?

Comment: Не совсем понял суть, но думаю да, если меньше 0 то всё, не обязательно -10 может быть

Comment: большое спасибо, это помогло!